# Pushing view controller with custom animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pushviewcontroller

Is it possible to make a custom push view controller animation like the image? The basic idea is to push the view normally, but without moving the current view (that calls the `pushViewController...`).

[image: ex]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, that can be done. I made a project where I did it like this:

```
-(void)slideInController:(RDSlideController *) next {
    next.presentingVC = self;
    next.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x + 320, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view.window addSubview:next.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:slideTime animations:^{
        next.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.view.window.rootViewController = next;
    }];
}
```

The view controllers that I slid in were subclasses of RDSlideController (so I could have the presentingVC property and some other things), but that's not really necessary. Basically, you just instantiate the new controller, set its view's frame to be off screen to the right, add that view to the window, then animate the frame to the current view's frame. Finally, you switch out the view controllers so that the new one is now the root view controller of the window.

Comment: slideTime is almost always 0.4 seconds in iOS by the way.

Comment: That's the answer. I didn't know the [UIView window] property. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Is there any simple way to dismiss or I'll have to move the view frame to out of the screen?

Comment: @Alberto, no, there's no simple way to dismiss. The old view isn't present any more so you need to get the old controller back, insert its view below (in the order sense) the current view, then slide off the current view.

Comment: @rdelmar No problem. Anyway, it's a clever solution (for both questions). Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by adding subview and animating view which we want to add.
When we are adding give animation to move next view from left edge to right edge. And vise versa with removing view.